# In Luke 24:30 is the "blessing" on the road to Emmaus the Jewish Kaddish Prayer? And if so, what would be the significance of that?

Tags: referent-identification, prayer

I saw that someone said in another Christian discussion forum, that - the "blessing" of Luke 24:30, on the road to Emmaus, was the Jewish "Kaddish Prayer" - a prayer said at meals, and mourning, and that is was what sparked the opening of the disciples eyes, to finally recognize Jesus. If this is true, what is the significance of Jesus saying the Kaddish prayer (the individual was asked but never replied)?

> BSB Luke 24: 29But they pleaded with Him, “Stay with us, for it is
>   nearly evening and the day is almost over.” So He went in to stay with
>   them. 30While He was reclining at the table with them, He took bread,
>   **spoke a blessing** and broke it, and gave it to them. 31Then t**heir eyes
>   were opened and they recognized Jesus**—and He disappeared from their
>   sight

---

> May His great name be exalted and sanctified. In the world which He
>   created according to His will! May He establish His kingdom during
>   your lifetime and during your days and during the lifetimes of all the
>   House of Israel, speedily and very soon! And say, Amen.
>
> May His great name be blessed for ever, and to all eternity!
>
> Blessed and praised, glorified and exalted, extolled and honored,
>   adored and lauded be the name of the Holy One, blessed be He, above
>   and beyond all the blessings, hymns, praises and consolations that are
>   uttered in the world! And say, Amen.
>
> May the prayers and supplications of all Israel be accepted by their
>   Father who is in Heaven; And say, Amen.
>
> May there be abundant peace from heaven, and life upon us and upon all
>   Israel; And say, Amen.
>
> May He who makes peace in His high places grant peace upon us and upon
>   all Israel; And say, Amen.
>
> http://getkaddish.com/prayer/

For more information about the Kaddish:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaddish

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: The title should read, "Luke 24:30, On The Road to Emaus - Was the Blessing the Jewish Kaddish Prayer, and what would be the significance of that?" I don't know what happened there.

Comment: Thanks, @Mortaryan, Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange. We are glad you are here! You can feel free to edit your question at any time by clicking edit above or clicking: [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18374). When you have a moment, please take a moment to take the site [tour] and review some of our [guidelines for participants](https://goo.gl/rDWUdw) and our [FAQs](https://goo.gl/tFFJZk). You may find the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) useful for figuring out how to do things like edit questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible blessing before breaking bread is the blessing before eating a meal with bread,

> ברוך אתה יי אלהינו מלך העולם המוציא לחם מן הארץ
>
> Blessed are you, LORD our God, king of the universe, who brings forth bread from the earth

This blessing was said at the time of Jesus.

Kaddish is historically later than the time of Jesus. Kaddish is only said after study or prayer, or as a recognition of a division between one section of prayer and another. Kaddish never was and never is said at meals.

The saying of one particular form of the Kaddish by adult male mourners in their first year of mourning for a relative of the first degree during regular public prayer services dates from the middle ages and is a custom of western Jewish communities, not of the Palestinian and oriental Jewish communities.